# How to persist session in firefox when calling another servlet in the parent window

Tags: java, firefox, servlets

I am using `Window.open("servletUrl","_parent","")` in my code to call the servlet for downloading a file; I am also using session object containing set of **dto** in my servlet.

But when I am using `Window.open("servletUrl","_parent","")` **session attributes** are getting destroyed in *firefox* but not in *IE8* .

Does anyone have any solution to how to make it work in firefox?

Comment: have you mentioned <session-timeout> time in web.xml?

Comment: no session timeout mentioned

Comment: is it i have to mention session time out in web.xml

Comment: its a good practice to set the timeout time.set the timeout time and then try.